# Invariant Manifolds of ODE

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider
\begin{align}
   \dot x=f(x(t)),\qquad (1)
\end{align}
where for all $t\in[0,\infty)$,  $x(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and  $f:D\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuously differentiable, where $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open.
For all $t\ge 0$ and all $x_0\in D$, let $\phi_t:D\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $\phi_t(x_0)$ is the solution $x(t)$  of (1) with the initial condition $x_0$.

Let $r>0$, and define
\begin{align}
    Z\triangleq\bigcap\limits_{\ell=1}^\infty\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \mbox{There exists $t>\ell$ such that} \|\phi_t(x)\|>r\},
\end{align}
which is the set of all trajectories with $\limsup_{\tau\to\infty} \|x(\tau)\|>r$.

Can we show that for all $t\ge 0$, $\phi_t(Z)=Z$?

Here's my attempt: I can show that for all $t\ge 0$, $\phi_t(Z)\subset Z$. This is easy to see using the definition of $Z$, that is, $Z$ is positive invariant with respect to (1). However, I cannot show that for all $t\ge 0$, $Z\subset \phi_t(Z)$. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is t not allowed to be negative? Because then you can define the inverse of the flow, which would be $\phi_{-t}$.

Comment: I guess we consider negative $t$ but I dont see how that can help

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that $Z\subset\phi_t(Z)$, we have to show that for all $x\in Z$  there is a $y\in Z$ such that $x=\phi_t(y)$.

Let $y=\phi_{-t}(x)$ and  prove that $y\in Z$. Indeed, given $\mathscr{l}\in\{1, \dots, \infty\}$ there exists a $t_0>\mathscr{l}$ such that $‖\phi_{t_0}()‖>$. Then
$$
‖\phi_{t_0+t}(y)‖ = ‖\phi_{t_0}(\phi_t(y))‖=‖\phi_{t_0}(\phi_{t-t}(x))‖=‖\phi_{t_0}(x)‖>r.
$$